# How to tell if an npm package was installed globally or locally

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I am installing [Grunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunt_(software)), [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js), npm, [Bower](https://bower.io/), and grunt-cli on [Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7).

The instructions say I should run the install commands with the *-g* flag for global.

How can I check if I used the -g flag when I installed? It will take a lot of time to uninstall them and reinstall.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Use the `list` command with the `-g` flag to see all packages that are installed globally:

`npm list -g`

To check if a specific package is installed globally, you can provide the name of package (`grunt` in this case) as seen below:

`npm list -g grunt`

Or you can use `grep` to filter on package names:

`npm list -g | grep grunt`

Source: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls

Comment: For a boolean "installed or not?" check, try using `--depth`. For example: `npm list --depth 1 --global csats-mturk > /dev/null 2>&1`.[Here's a more detailed example](https://gitlab.com/snippets/3883).

Comment: @AdamMonsen , I was looking for _top level_ installation of tern. I used `npm list --depth 0 --global tern` to check if tern was installed globally as if `npm install -g tern`

Comment: `grep` seems like a fairly reliable solution given the comments about npm exiting with an error due to unmet dependencies

Answer (score 43):

```
npm list --depth 1 --global packagename > /dev/null 2>&1
```

You can then check the exit status to see if it's installed or not. Thanks [Adam Monsen](https://gitlab.com/snippets/3883).

Comment: thanks for `--depth 1`! that's what I was looking for. Actually I'm using now `npm list --depth 0 -g`

Comment: For some reason `$?` always returns `1` for me, even if the package IS installed or NOT installed.

Comment: WARNING: npm will always exit with an error if any of your packages have unmet dependencies, **even if the package is installed**. @Kayvar this is why npm is returning 1 for you.

Comment: There is a warning (to [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr))): *"npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead."*

Answer (score 25):

To check if a specific package is installed globally, execute:

```
npm list -g [package-name]
```

Let's take Grunt as an example. If it is installed globally, you should see something like this:

```
npm list -g grunt
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── grunt@0.4.5
```

If it is not installed globally, you should see something like this

```
npm list -g grunt
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── (empty)
```

To check if a specific package is installed locally you can execute the same commands as above, but without the -g parameter.

Source: [How to check if npm package was installed globally or locally](http://resolvethis.com/how-to-check-if-npm-package-was-installed-globally-or-locally/).

Answer (score 10):

You can list all global packages with the command:

```
npm ls -g
```

Or check for a specific package with:

```
npm ls -g [package-name]
```

For example: `npm ls -g @angular/cli`

Comment: There is a warning (to [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr))): *"npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead."*

Answer (score 7):

In Windows we use the following command to find out whether the package is installed or not.  Please refer image for details.

```
npm list -g | find "create"
```

[image: sample result]

Answer (score 1):

**From your package with `sindresorhus/is-installed-globally`**

https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-installed-globally

Usage:

```
const isInstalledGlobally = require('is-installed-globally');

// With `npm install your-package`
console.log(isInstalledGlobally);
//=> false

// With `npm install --global your-package`
console.log(isInstalledGlobally);
//=> true
```

I found this useful when I had to distribute prebuilt files with my package: [How to publish a npm package with distribution files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642477/how-to-publish-a-npm-package-with-distribution-files/59407033#59407033) With this package, I can check if the installation is local or global, and then use relative paths for local installations, [as shown here](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirodown/blob/7644ed8d86db3fe9bbbcd438f4386ae825ce9251/cirodown#L161).

Comment: The examples aren't very clear. How would one want to check if "gulp-cli" has been installed?

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward note that this method is only to check from within a dependency inside a package you control.