# yarn publish fails because dist folder is added to gitignore

Tags: git, npm, yarnpkg

Yarn would like to add a git tag when publishing a node module. However this folder is added to gitignore.

```
 yarn publish dist

Output:
    The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
    dist/package.json
    Use -f if you really want to add them.
    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/publish for documentation about this command.
```

How can you keep dist in gitignore, but make an exception for yarn to be able to add the dist folder to a git commit?

I've tried:

-.npmignore without dist folder (-->ignored by yarn)

-add a files array to package.json

-anyone has other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not clear how `yarn publish` and a Git commit are related. Is adding `dist/` to a Git commit actually your goal, as stated?

Comment: Yarn publish also pushes git tags whenever you run the publish command

Comment: Interesting; thanks for clarifying @Vincent!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to publish a npm package with distribution files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642477/how-to-publish-a-npm-package-with-distribution-files)

Comment: Not really because that question is about what sources to publish and doesnt clarify  about yarn doing automatically git tagging

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this (more of a work-around, I suppose), is to call `yarn publish` with the `--no-git-tag-version` option, e.g.

```
yarn publish dist/ --no-git-tag-version
```

Comment: This also works. I ended up splitting the publishing step in two. 1) yarn pack which builds a gzip archive and 2)yarn publish that archive. Than git tagging is also skipped