# npm publish only publish index.js and excluding everything else

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, npm-publish, tsdx

**Problems**

I'm trying to publish my own SDK in npm. When I'm trying to install my packages, my dist folder only shows index.js

Code:

Here is my `package.json` file. It already includes main and files, https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts.

```json
{
  "version": "0.1.4",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsdx watch",
    "build": "tsdx build",
    "test": "tsdx test --passWithNoTests",
    "lint": "tsdx lint",
    "prepare": "tsdx build",
    "prepublish": "tsdx build",
    "size": "size-limit",
    "analyze": "size-limit --why"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "tsdx lint"
    }
  },
  "name": "@grammable/sdk",
  "author": "peanut butter jelly",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/grammable/grammable-sdk",
  "repository": "https://github.com/grammable/grammable-sdk",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "module": "dist/grammable.esm.js",
  "size-limit": [
    {
      "path": "dist/grammable.cjs.production.min.js",
      "limit": "10 KB"
    },
    {
      "path": "dist/grammable.esm.js",
      "limit": "10 KB"
    }
  ],
}
```

I removed my devDependencies and dependencies to remove unnecessary lines. Can someone help me?

This is my folder structure.
[folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvAGE.png)

Update: I have tried using `npx npm-packlist`. It has everything I need, but when I npm publish it, it only builds index.js

Edit 2:

```
npm notice   @grammable/sdk@0.1.4
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
npm notice 35.1kB LICENSE      
npm notice 237B   README.md    
npm notice 184B   dist/index.js
npm notice 1.6kB  package.json 
npm notice === Tarball Details ===
```

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr:** When a `.npmignore` file is not specified, npm will use your `.gitignore` file setting, where `dist` and the files in it are likely to get ignored.

Your `dist/index.js` isn't ignored by this rule because you specified it in the `main` field of your `package.json`.

And there is this particular part in [npm doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#files) about the `files` field in `package.json` also explains more clearly why this behavior happens.

> Some special files and directories are also included or excluded regardless of whether they exist in the files array.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31642553/12847183) the issue can be solved when you specify your own `.npmignore` file.

Comment: so i just tried creating `.npmignore` in the same of my `.gitignore` directory, and both of them only contains `node_modules`. once i clicked that `npm publish`, all other files automatically get deleted. @kvooak

Comment: This is my ["files" field declaration](https://imgur.com/a/uB4AEOd) in a `package.json` file of an npm package I published. In there instead of `dist` I put `dist/*` just to be sure, and it worked. You can try with other glob patterns like `**/*` and such to see which works for you. @EdwardTanoto

Comment: hmm i already tried, still doesnt work though. i already deleted my package lock json and node modules as well, and changed my files into dist/*, I'll edit the details in the post @kvooak.

Comment: @EdwardTanoto have you solved this issue?

Comment: Hi @kvooak, may I contact you through discord or anything? There is a new development and it's almost solved.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Did we achieve any resolution on this?

Comment: Hi @MuKa, unfortunately no, however I’m still interested and if you figure out something eventually please share. I’m also happy to look into this again with my own npm packages

Comment: @kvooak, I think it started spitting out more files into the tgz when I removed the "files" attribute in packages.json. I am using a .npmignore to override the exclusions made in .gitignore. I initially had the "files" values as "dist", "src" and then "dist/*", "src" but neither combinations worked.

Comment: This seems to be a new behavior with NPM 9. I haven't had any problem before upgrading from 8 to 9. However, changing files from "dist/*" to "dist" worked for me.

Comment: I was having same issue, and fixed with those patterns: 
"files": ["dist/**/**.js", "dist/**/**.d.ts", "!dist/tests/**" ]