Best practices to compile typescript projects
I am currently working on different projects that use the same UI, so I took some time to refactor the UI components ( coded in typescript / React, and being executed in Chromium environments ).
I currently have a monorepo, with the structure :
app/
  project1/
  project2/
sdk/
  sharedUiProject/

My "sharedUiProject" is being compiled using TSC. I used the following config for my file :
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "Node16",
    "target": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "Node16",
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowArbitraryExtensions": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}

Which made me have, for each file of my project, a js, a d.ts and their respective .map files in my dist folder.
However, I wonder if this is the right thing to export or not. I do not think my "client projects" need all of these files especially that I am only exporting 1 component out of it. Do you have any ressource I can check in order to know how typescript projects should be compiled ?
I created a monorepo and shared the ui. Now I am wondering if my config to share the project is good

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642477/how-can-i-publish-an-npm-package-with-distribution-files
