# why react toastify doesn't work in my project?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, jsx, react-toastify

I am trying to use react toastify in this function inside my signup page

```
  const submitionHandler = ()=>{
    let userData = {name,email,password,phone,country,gender};
    //validate data

    //handle api
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/admins',userData)
    .then(res=>{
      toast.success("User has been registered successfully!");
      navigate(`/login`);
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      toast.error(err.message);
    })
  }
```

I installed the library and imported these files

```
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
```

I rendered toast container inside the app.js too

```
<>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
          <Route path='/signup' element={<SignUp />} />
          <Route path='/Users' element={<Users />} />
          <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />

        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <ToastContainer/>
</>
```

I imported this in app.js

```
import SignUp from './pages/SignUp';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

everything is working properly but the toastify notification doesn't show up

Answer (score 0):

Following your toastify document https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify

1- you need to add  `<ToastContainer />` in place that you need to present the toast.

2- use toast hook.

Check the following example.

```
import React from 'react';

  import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
  import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
  
  function App(){
    const notify = () => toast("Wow so easy!");

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={notify}>Notify!</button>
        <ToastContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: actually I put it inside app.js so I can use it in all others pages I want it to show up once the user log in or sign up

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in your import in your app.js mainly so try the following.

```
 import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
    import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
    
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        {/* all you do here... */}
      </Routes>
      <ToastContainer />
    </Router>
```

try this and let me know

Comment: nah it didn't work too

Comment: 1st verify if the package is installed correctly you can use `npm info YOUR_PACKAGE version` or consider going through [how-to-tell-if-an-npm-package-was-installed-globally-or-locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104276/how-to-tell-if-an-npm-package-was-installed-globally-or-locally) for the same ,also can you verify the case that the toast is not happening in any page or just the singup page ?

Comment: the version is 10.0.3 it's not installed globally and yes it didn't happen in all pages

Comment: can you verifi that the code block is being executed example `const submitionHandler = ()=>{
    let userData = {name,email,password,phone,country,gender};
    //validate data

    //handle api
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/admins',userData)
    .then(res=>{ console.log("in block state00");
      toast.success("User has been registered successfully!");
     console.log("in block state02");  navigate(`/login`);console.log("in block state03");
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      toast.error(err.message);
    })
  }`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are importing `ToastContainer` from "react-bootstrap" instead of "react-toastify"